# Can't make Pandas difference function work in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to find the difference between values from previous months in the data. The data can be seen [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AvY_LfJENU3yvh8ALj9SD6K0GldG) . I'm using Spyder. The code I'm using is below:

```
import pandas as pd

#Ask User to input location of import file

print('Input file location')
filename = input()

#Importing csv file to importdata_df datafram
data = pd.read_csv(filename)

#melt data 


melt = data.melt(id_vars='HS Code', var_name='Month', value_name='Imports')

melt = melt.sort_values(['Month', 'HS Code'])


#Add variables for last month imports and last month difference
melt2 = melt.copy()
melt2['Last_Month_Imports'] = melt2.groupby(['HS Code'])['Imports'].shift()
melt2['Last_Month_Diff'] = melt2.groupby(['HS Code'])['Last_Month_Imports'].diff()
melt2 = melt2.dropna()
print(melt2.head())
```

However, when I run this code I receive the following error:

```
line 34, in <module>
    melt2['Last_Month_Diff'] = melt2.groupby(['HS Code'])['Last_Month_Imports'].diff()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 622, in wrapper
    raise ValueError

ValueError
```

Comment: I think `HS Code` was turned in index so you can't use for the groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `diff()`:

```
df[column].diff()
```

will return the difference to previous row in column

Comment: I don't understand, is there a difference between diff() and dif()?

Comment: apologies, is a type the function is with diff()

Comment: So I tried to run it as melt2['Last_Month_Diff'] = melt2['Last_Month_Imports'].diff() but I'm still getting an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'

Comment: It seems that you have string in your Last_Month_Imports.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, I used fillna to replace NaN to 0s and I stil get the same error.

Comment: do melt2.info() and check that the column you want are float or int.

Comment: I get the following when I try that: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 104148 entries, 45937 to 37885
Data columns (total 4 columns):
HS Code               104148 non-null int64
Month                 104148 non-null object
Imports               104148 non-null object
Last_Month_Imports    104148 non-null object
dtypes: int64(1), object(3)
memory usage: 4.0+ MB
None

Comment: Is a non-null object a string?

Comment: your column very likely has strings and numbers on it. You need to remove everything that is not a number and convert the column to numbers to try any math function

Comment: THANKS MAN! You were right, when I imported the values I used the thousands argument to make sure the values are inputted as numbers, data = pd.read_csv(filename, thousands=',')
.